Does Japanese advertises selling something with full price?
Context: I am reading a manga. The girl is promoting a new kind of cloth hanger. The final part she said "今ならお値段 フルプライス!" which may be "(buy) it now for its full price".
Does I translated it wrongly? Or she really promote selling it with full price? What is the point of advertising selling something "with full price" in Japan's culture? Shouldn't she just say some thing like "my hanger is good", "its price is good for your pocket, too"?
Thank you.


No, your translation is correct, and it is just a little joke to make readers chuckle. The whole text in the background is a parody of typical shopping program trope, which ends in "...now only costs:", but no discount is actually made in the punch line.
If the plot hasn't changed from the novel, the product was so tempting for ベンノ that she needed no price negotiation.

I see, thank you very much.
